# Show related item django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have the following models:

class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Element(models.Model):

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

class Topic(models.Model):

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

element = models.ForeignKey(Element)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

I basically need to add New topic in catégory id =1 and get only a list of élément belongs to category 1

I have created a view New topic in category id =1, but for fields element in form i get all elements for all categories

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you should add a `related_name` to the `category` field in the `Element` model.

ex

```py
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='elements')
```

Then when you have a topic object you can access the elements for the topic's category by doing `obj.category.elements`.

If you plan to get a list of posts in a category, you would do the same thing (obviously with a different name) to the FK from Topic to Category.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  i have add the finame but still not work, my problem is when i add New topic with ( topic name and element name should be a reference field with choices) i get alll éléments result for all categories even that i am in category 1

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand your question with what you are actually doing and give an example of what you expect vs what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

Hellow,

Below models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Element(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='elements', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    element = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    element = models.ForeignKey(KPI, related_name='topics', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='tickets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tickets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def new_topic(request, category_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    kpi = KPI.objects.select_related().filter(category=category_id)
    #user = User.objects.first()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
           topic = form.save(commit=False)
           topic.category = category
           topic.created_by = request.user
           topic.save()

       

           post = Post.objects.create(
                message=form.cleaned_data.get('message'),
                
                topic=topic
           )
           return redirect('category_topic', category_id=category.pk)
    else:

        form = NewTopicForm()

    return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'category': category, 'form':form}
                  )
```

forms.py

```
class NewTopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=6000)

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['subject', 'issue_date', 'message', 'element']
```

Some elements was created by admin interface such as

Category_1 elements_1
Category_1 elemnts_2
Category_2 elements_3

The quesion is when I need to create new topic in category_1, I need to show only elements belongs to category 1 not all elements

Thank you